# Facebook Statuses API

Tags: php, facebook, json, api

I'd just like to ask about a problem I'm facing with Facebook Graph API.
I've connected to Facebook successfully, stored the user ID, and user access_code into my DB

Now when viewing the site I'm building, it's using the `access_token` stored in my database, but doesn't show my facebook statuses....because the "session has expired"....

Is there anyway I can regenerate the access_token?

Thanks

Example:

```
$status = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userId.'/statuses?limit='.10.'&access_token='.$app_token;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User access tokens last only 1-2 hours.  There is a technique to get a 60 day token for your use.  It is explained here:  http://dominicminicoopers.blogspot.com/2012/03/facebook-access-tokens-and-offline.html Remember to get this extended access token prior to the short-lived access token expiring.  You must pass in a valid working user access token to pass to it. Do this serverside, not clientside because you have to use your app secret.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=[APP_ID]&
    client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=[EXISTING_NON-EXPIRED_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Remember to ask for the `user_status` permission when prompting the user. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms

Answer (score 0):

You cant regenerate it, but you can get a new one by having the user go through the oauth process again, it will return a new token - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: With that being the case, would this mean that each time my access_token runs out, I'd have to login again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get a long lived token. That will allow you to access the status even when the user is not loged in.
See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: hhmm...how would that work...because i've logged in, and my access token ends up lasting for 2 hours... I should be using this: "Exception 1: Desktop Apps"